# Is there a way to only clear a specific item from the recycle bin?

Tags: 2007, development, object-model

I know I can empty the recycle bin for a site collection with the following:

```
public static bool EmptyRecycleBin(string siteCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite(siteCollection))
                {
                    site.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);

                return false;
            }
        }
```

However this could cause issues and I'd like to only remove specific items (that I've deleted programatically) from here. Is there a way to do this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to find the ID SPRecycleBinItem and use [SPRecycleBinItemCollection.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprecyclebinitemcollection.delete%28v=office.12%29) or find the SPRecycleBinItem and use S[PRecycleBinItem.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprecyclebinitem.delete%28v=office.12%29)

This code deletes any instances of `Test.png` from the folder `Test` in the documentlibrary with rootfolder `TestDocs` from the recyclebin:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://sp2010"))
{
    var idsToDelete = new List<Guid>();
    foreach (SPRecycleBinItem item in site.RecycleBin)
    {
        if (item.DirName.Equals("TestDocs/Test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
         && item.LeafName.Equals("Test.png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            idsToDelete.Add(item.ID);
        }
    }
    site.RecycleBin.Delete(idsToDelete.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: How do I go about finding the ID if I only have the old filename?

Comment: You have to loop through all the Items and check DirName and LeafName

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm having no success doing this

Comment: Can't award the bounty for another six hours but this looks to work - thank-you!

Comment: Example added to answer