# Invalid URI when trying to empty recycle bin

Tags: 2007, development, object-model

Based on [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44578/is-there-a-way-to-only-clear-a-specific-item-from-the-recycle-bin) I wrote the following in my class for emptying the recycle bin:

```
public static void EmptyRecycleBinItem(string siteCollection, string originalLocation, string filename)
{
    try
    {
        using (var site = new SPSite(siteCollection))
        {
            site.RecycleBin.Delete((from SPRecycleBinItem item
                                    in site.RecycleBin
                                    where item.DirName.Equals(originalLocation, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                    && item.LeafName.Equals(filename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                    select item.ID).ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new UnableToEmptyRecycleBin(filename, ex);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this throws a URL error, specifically:

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
>   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind
>   uriKind)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)
>   at
>   Testing.RE.SharePoint.SharePointRecycleBin.EmptyRecycleBinItem(String
>   siteCollection, String originalLocation, String filename) in
>   C:\Dev\Testing.RE\Testing.RE.SharePoint\Testing.RE.SharePoint\SharePointRecycleBin.cs:line
>   57    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Testing.RE.SharePoint.SharePointRecycleBin.EmptyRecycleBinItem(String
>   siteCollection, String originalLocation, String filename) in
>   C:\Dev\Testing.RE\Testing.RE.SharePoint\Testing.RE.SharePoint\SharePointRecycleBin.cs:line
>   78    at Testing.RE.SharePoint.ListsAndItems.MoveListItems(String
>   siteURL, String sourceList, String destinationList, Boolean
>   retainMeta) in
>   C:\Dev\Testing.RE\Testing.RE.SharePoint\Testing.RE.SharePoint\ListsAndItems.cs:line
>   80   *** Exception Details ***

I've checked, and I'm passing strings into the method. I even simplified this down to the following, but still received the exception:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteCollection))
{
    var idsToDelete = new List<Guid>(); 

    foreach (SPRecycleBinItem item in site.RecycleBin)
    {
        if(item.LeafName.Equals(filename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            idsToDelete.Add(item.ID);
        }
    }

    site.RecycleBin.Delete(idsToDelete.ToArray());
}
```

I also tried changing:

```
if(item.LeafName.Equals(filename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

To be:

```
if (item.Title.Equals(filename, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

But had no luck.

The full class that calls this method (so you can see that I am, in fact, passing strings) is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Diagnostics;

// todo: Lists
// DeleteListItem
// WriteFileMetadata
// AddListEntry

// Throttling on copy methods

namespace Testing.RE.SharePoint
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to encapsulate methods that interact with SharePoint Lists and Libraries
    /// </summary>
    public class ListsAndItems
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Move items from a list to another list in the same site
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="siteURL">URL to the host site collection</param>
        /// <param name="sourceList">URL to the source list</param>
        /// <param name="destinationList">URL to the destination list</param>
        /// <param name="retainMeta">Option to retain meta data (created/modified dates) or create new ones</param>
        /// <returns>Boolean value, true for successful copy, false for a failed copy</returns>
        public bool MoveListItems(string siteURL, string sourceList, string destinationList, bool retainMeta)
        {
            OnSharePointOpeningSite(siteURL);

            using (var site = new SPSite(siteURL))
            {
                OnSharePointOpenedSite(siteURL);

                using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    OnSharePointGetRelativeURL(web.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    try
                    {
                        // Get your source and destination libraries
                        var source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + sourceList);
                        var destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + destinationList);

                        OnSharePointSourceSet(source);
                        OnSharePointDestinationSet(destination);

                        // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
                        SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

                        // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
                        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

                        OnSharePointProcessItem(items.Count, source.ToString(), destination.ToString());

                        var fileCount = 0;
                        // Now to move the files and the metadata
                        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            //Get the file associated with the item
                            SPFile file = item.File;

                            OnSharePointProcessFile(folder.Url + "/" + file.Name);

                            // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                            SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(), file.Properties, true);

                            if (retainMeta)
                            {
                                SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                                WriteFileMetaDataFiletoFile(item, newItem);
                            }

                            file.Delete();
                            SharePointRecycleBin.EmptyRecycleBinItem(site.ToString(), source.ToString(), file.Name.ToString());

                            fileCount++;
                        }

                        OnSharePointProcessList(fileCount, source.ToString(), destination.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException fex)
                    {
                        OnError("Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection. \n\nSite URL: " 
                                    + siteURL + " \nSource List: " + sourceList + " \nDestination List: " + destinationList + "\n", false, fex);

                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        OnError("General Exception: ", true, ex);

                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Move items from one SharePoint list to another in another site
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceSiteURL">The URL to the source site collection</param>
        /// <param name="sourceList">The URL to the source list</param>
        /// <param name="destinationSiteURL">The URL to the destination site collection</param>
        /// <param name="destinationList">The URL to the destination list</param>
        /// <param name="retainMeta">Option to retain meta data (created/modified dates) or create new ones</param>
        /// <returns>Boolean value, true for successful copy, false for a failed copy</returns>
        public bool MoveListItemsSiteToSite(string sourceSiteURL, string sourceList, string destinationSiteURL, string destinationList, bool retainMeta)
        {
            OnSharePointOpeningSite(sourceSiteURL);

            using (SPSite sourceSite = new SPSite(sourceSiteURL))
            {
                OnSharePointOpenedSite(sourceSiteURL);

                using (SPWeb sourceWeb = sourceSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    OnSharePointGetRelativeURL(sourceWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    try
                    {
                        // Get your source library
                        var source = sourceWeb.GetList(sourceWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + sourceList);

                        OnSharePointSourceSet(source);

                        // Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
                        SPListItemCollection items = source.Items;

                        int fileCount = 0;

                        OnSharePointOpeningSite(destinationSiteURL);

                        using (var destSite = new SPSite(destinationSiteURL))
                        {
                            OnSharePointOpenedSite(destinationSiteURL);

                            using (var destinationWeb = destSite.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                OnSharePointGetRelativeURL(destinationWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);

                                // get destination library
                                SPList destination = destinationWeb.GetList(destinationWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + destinationList);

                                OnSharePointDestinationSet(destination);

                                // Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
                                SPFolder destinationFolder = destinationWeb.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

                                OnSharePointProcessItem(items.Count, source.ToString(), destination.ToString());

                                // Now to move the files and the metadata
                                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                                {
                                    //Get the file associated with the item
                                    SPFile file = item.File;

                                    // Add event handler
                                    OnSharePointProcessFile(destinationFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name);

                                    // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
                                    SPFile newFile = destinationFolder.Files.Add(destinationFolder.Url + "/" + file.Name, file.OpenBinary(),
                                                                                 file.Properties, true);

                                    if (retainMeta)
                                    {
                                        SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
                                        WriteFileMetaDataFiletoFile(item, newItem);
                                    }

                                    file.Delete();

                                    SharePointRecycleBin.EmptyRecycleBinItem(sourceSite.ToString(), source.ToString(), file.Name);

                                    fileCount++;
                                }
                                OnSharePointProcessList(fileCount, source.ToString(), destination.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException fex)
                    {
                        OnError("Unable to set a location. Please check that paths for source and destination libraries are correct and relative to the site collection. \n\nSource Site: " 
                                    + sourceSiteURL + " \nSource List: " + sourceList + " \nDestination Site: " + destinationSiteURL + " \nDestination List: " + destinationList + "\n", false, fex);

                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        OnError("General Exception: ", true, ex);

                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// overwrites a list items meta data with meta data from another file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceItem">The source item to take meta data from</param>
        /// <param name="destinationItem">The destination item to set meta data from the source item to</param>
        public static void WriteFileMetaDataFiletoFile(SPListItem sourceItem, SPListItem destinationItem)
        {
            destinationItem["Editor"] = sourceItem["Editor"];
            destinationItem["Modified"] = sourceItem["Modified"];
            destinationItem["Modified By"] = sourceItem["Modified By"];
            destinationItem["Author"] = sourceItem["Author"];
            destinationItem["Created"] = sourceItem["Created"];
            destinationItem["Created By"] = sourceItem["Created By"];

            destinationItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
        }


        #region Events

        internal void OnSharePointProcessFile(string itemPath)
        {           
            if (_sharePointProcessedFile == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointProcessFileEventArgs(itemPath);
            _sharePointProcessedFile(this, e);
        }

        internal void OnSharePointProcessItem(int itemCount, string source, string destination)
        {
            if (_sharePointProcessItem == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointProcessItemEventArgs(itemCount, source, destination);

            _sharePointProcessItem(this, e);
        }


        internal void OnSharePointProcessList(int itemCount, string source, string destination)
        {
            if (_sharePointProcessList == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointProcessListEventArgs(itemCount, source, destination);

            _sharePointProcessList(this, e);
        }


        internal void OnSharePointOpeningSite(string siteName)
        {
            if (_sharePointOpeningSite == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointOpeningSiteEventArgs(siteName);

            _sharePointOpeningSite(this, e);
        }

        internal void OnSharePointOpenedSite(string siteName)
        {
            if (_sharePointOpenedSite == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointOpenedSiteEventArgs(siteName);

            _sharePointOpenedSite(this, e);
        }

        internal void OnSharePointGetRelativeURL(string siteCollection)
        {
            if (_sharePointRelativeURL == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointWebRelativeURLEventArgs(siteCollection);

            _sharePointRelativeURL(this, e);
        }

        internal void OnSharePointDestinationSet(SPList destination)
        {
            if (_sharepointDestination == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointDestinationSetEventArgs(destination);

            _sharepointDestination(this, e);
        }

        internal void OnSharePointSourceSet(SPList source)
        {
            if (_sharepointSource == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointSourceSetEventArgs(source);

            _sharepointSource(this, e);
        }

        internal void OnError(string message, bool showException, Exception exception)
        {
            if (_sharePointOnError == null) return;

            var e = new SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs(message, showException, exception);

            _sharePointOnError(this, e);
        }

        private EventHandler<SharePointProcessFileEventArgs> _sharePointProcessedFile;
        private EventHandler<SharePointProcessListEventArgs> _sharePointProcessList;
        private EventHandler<SharePointOpeningSiteEventArgs> _sharePointOpeningSite;
        private EventHandler<SharePointOpenedSiteEventArgs> _sharePointOpenedSite;
        private EventHandler<SharePointWebRelativeURLEventArgs> _sharePointRelativeURL;
        private EventHandler<SharePointDestinationSetEventArgs> _sharepointDestination;
        private EventHandler<SharePointSourceSetEventArgs> _sharepointSource;
        private EventHandler<SharePointProcessItemEventArgs> _sharePointProcessItem;
        private EventHandler<SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs> _sharePointOnError;

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for handling exceptions
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointOnErrorEventsArgs> SharePointOnError
        {
            add { _sharePointOnError += value; }
            remove { _sharePointOnError += value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a file is being processed
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointProcessFileEventArgs> SharePointProcessFile
        {
            add { _sharePointProcessedFile += value; }
            remove { _sharePointProcessedFile += value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a site is attempting to open
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointOpeningSiteEventArgs> SharePointOpeningSite
        {
            add { _sharePointOpeningSite += value; }
            remove { _sharePointOpeningSite -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a site has been successfully opened
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointOpenedSiteEventArgs> SharePointOpenedSite
        {
            add { _sharePointOpenedSite += value; }
            remove { _sharePointOpenedSite -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when source/destination and filecount are established and a copy is about to initiate
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointProcessItemEventArgs> SharePointProcessItem
        {
            add { _sharePointProcessItem += value; }
            remove { _sharePointProcessItem -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a list has started processing
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointProcessListEventArgs> SharePointProcessList
        {
            add { _sharePointProcessList += value; }
            remove { _sharePointProcessList -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a web relative URL has been retreived from the site collection name
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointWebRelativeURLEventArgs> SharePointWebRelativeURL
        {
            add { _sharePointRelativeURL += value; }
            remove { _sharePointRelativeURL -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a destination location has been assigned
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointDestinationSetEventArgs> SharePointDestinationSet
        {
            add { _sharepointDestination += value; }
            remove { _sharepointDestination -= value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event for when a source location has been assigned
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SharePointSourceSetEventArgs> SharePointSourceSet
        {
            add { _sharepointSource += value; }
            remove { _sharepointSource -= value; }
        }

    #endregion 
    }
}
```

What is this error telling me and what would be the proposed resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your recycle bin code - at least not yet. According to the error message, the code is failing when trying to construct the SPSite instance:

> System.UriFormatException: **Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.**
>    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>    at **Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)**

In your class, change:

```
SharePointRecycleBin.EmptyRecycleBinItem(site.ToString(), source.ToString(), file.Name.ToString());
```

to:

```
SharePointRecycleBin.EmptyRecycleBinItem(site.Url, source.ToString(), file.Name.ToString());
```

You may also want to consider an override of EmptyRecycleBinItem that accepts an instance of SPSite as the first parameter, rather than a string in the form of a URL. That way you won't have to pass the URL from one SPSite instance just to create another within EmptyRecycleBinItem.