# Get actual item from SPRecycleBin

Tags: 2013, splistitem, delete, recycle-bin

Similar to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44578/is-there-a-way-to-only-clear-a-specific-item-from-the-recycle-bin), I need to permanently delete only specific items from the recycle bin. I need to know more than just their names, however, and `SPRecycleBinItem` seems to have only have a `LeafName` and `DirName` property, no `Item` property to see what the deleted item actually contains (I need the `SPListItem`).

Does anyone know if there's a way to actually get the deleted objects? Perhaps a hidden recycle bin list buried somewhere?

As for why I need to do this, I'm trying to design a way to programmatically delete content types that actually works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user deletes a document seems like document binaries are deleted from table `AllDocs` to `RecycleBin` where it only keeps **some** information about document. These tables are in content database of that application.

I am not able to figure out as what it does with `<Binary data>` when a document record is moved from alldocs to recyclebin table. as this **Binary data** keeps all meta data about document and when you restore document, it uses it to restore document.

I don't think there is any easy way to get other properties of deleted document unless you do a hack which will going to be complex and **HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED**. You might want to change the logic of your solution.

Comment: Too bad. Maybe someday they'll actually improve the API.